# Can I write applets (database) to run in a shared drive on a server

Tags: java, applet

Can I write a java applet (in a webpage) to control an SQlite database in a shared drive on a server, so that all employees in my company have access to it?

At the end, I want to give all employees a link (/server/myFile/program.html) and they can access the information they need. I also want to embed a pdf engine like iText to use in generating reports. Are applets suitable for this sort of task, or will I encounter issues relating to security manager. I need your suggestions.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you need shared access to a resource like SQLite, you might be best served to split you applet up into the UI component (the applet) and a server component that controls access to the SQLite database. While SQLite supports multi-client access, you'll probably find you need better control over the database resoruces than you'd get directly accessing via an applet (and I'm not entirely sure that the JRE sandbox will let you access a shared filesystem)

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Dataknife's answer (because all of what he said is correct and I don't want to be one of those guys who parrot(repeat) everyone), The JRE in sandbox will not allow you to access a shared file system. There is an easy...ish solution to this though. At the very least then throughout testing you can just self sign your applet. this is explained here --> [explanation](http://linuxpoison.blogspot.com/2008/06/how-to-create-self-signed-certificates.html)
or i can just simplify this for you,

1. open `cmd.exe`
2. type in following: `cd "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin"`
   ---or something similar, location it points to must have the following files: `keytool.exe` and  `jarsigner.exe`
3. now that command prompt is pointing there type in this line:`keytool -genkey -keyalg rsa -alias test -validity 3650` then follow the prompts. This will create a key named 'test' that will sign a jar file for 10 years.
4. Now that you have this, compile your class files and export them into a .jar file
5. now here is where you accually sign it. Go back to cmd.exe and type in the following: `jarsigner "PATH_TO_YOUR_JAR_FILE\YOUR_FILE.jar" test` enter passwords
6. it should now be signed, to check if it is signed type the following: `jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs "PATH_TO_YOUR_JAR_FILE\YOUR_FILE.jar"`
7. To run the applet embbed it in an html file as normal but add the code `archive="YOUR_FILE.jar"` after the code part of the tag

Now, in the case that you have to debug it several times from the browser, you DO NOT have to reexport the project. First run program(to compile class files) Then open your jar file using winRAR, delete any class files you have changed since the last time you signed it, then manually add them by using the add button, going to the bin folder of your project, then selecting the class files you deleted(and any added since last sign). now go to cmd.exe and repeat steps 2, 5, and 6 from above.

Hope this helps you out,
Dylan